# Eclipse Python align a block of code

Tags: python, eclipse

This is more of an IDE question :

In Eclipse + PyDev , how can I align a chunk of code with some line ?

Let's say I have this code

```
  myList=[]
   for i in list
      print i
      do a bunch of other stuff
```

And in this example I wrote lets say that for some reason the for loop got indented once space when it shouldn't have - it needs to be aligned with the list("myList") definition. How can I indent\align the whole code block of the loop to the left so it is under list? Right now with no better solution I go line by line and move it to the correct spot . Tried using tab , no good ...I bet there's some easy answer for this...

Comment: It should just work if you select the effected lines and use `tab` to increase indent and `shift+tab` do decrease indent.

Comment: what's your Eclipse version ?

Answer (score 0):

Try :

> window > preferences > pydev > editor > tab length

and set tab length to 4.

Ps. I also think that select all your code ( highlight them). Then, `Source > correct indentation` would also do the trick. I haven't try this yet though.